# Confusion defining java subclasses from a generic superclass

Tags: java, generics, subclass, superclass

I'm modifying some old code that used generics in super and subclasses, and I've been going around in circles for the last couple of hours trying to get this sorted out.

This is my superclass.  It's going to keep track of superdetections and subdetections, which may be different types but will all extend Superclass.

```
public class Superclass<T extends Superclass<T,U>, U extends Superclass<T,U>> {
  private Vector<T> subDetections;
  private Vector<U> superDetections;

  public Superclass() {
    subDetections = new Vector<T>();
    superDetections = new Vector<U>();
  }

  public void addSub(T sub) {
    subDetections.add(sub);
  }

  public void addSup(U sup) {
    superDetections.add(sup);
  }
}
```

There is one more generic class for some added functionality:

```
public class SubclassA<T extends Superclass<T,U>, U extends Superclass<T,U>> extends Superclass<T, U> {
  public SubclassA() {
    super();
  }
}
```

And here are 2 concrete classes:

```
public class SubclassB extends Superclass<SubclassB, SubclassB> {
  public SubclassB() {
    super();
  }
}


public class SubclassB2 extends Superclass<SubclassB2, SubclassB2> {
  public SubclassB2() {
    super();
  }
}
```

What I need to do is define SubclassC that extends SubclassA, but defines the first parameter (generic T) as SubclassB while keeping the second parameter generic.  Something like this:

```
public class SubclassC extends SubclassA<SubclassB, ???what goes here???> {}
```

I get a bound mismatch on SubclassB, and I don't even know what to put in the second spot.

I also need to create an instance of SubclassA which will hold a SubclassB object and SubclassB2 object, but can't figure that out either:

```
SubclassA<SubclassB, SubclassB2> subA = new SubclassA<SubclassB, SubclassB2>();
```

Bound mismatch errors again.  I don't understand why SubclassB/SubclassB2 are not valid substitutes for Superclass.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would very much appreciate it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I think you're heading into a world of pain by having the class contain itself. I suggest you simplify the design to just `MyPojoClass<T, U>`.

Comment: I'm already in that world - I've been banging my head against the table for the last hour.  Unfortunately I can't completely rework the code.  It's quite a few years old, defining classes like `SubclassC extends SubclassA` and ignoring the 'raw type' warnings.

Comment: Completely rework the code. You know it needs to be done. And you're the guy who's going to do it.